# Did Sora / Kite ever return to the world?

Tags: .hack

Toward the end of *.hack//Beyond The World* (like the last two minutes), it's announced that THE WORLD would come back online and Sora is asked if she was going to play again. However, at the very end of the movie we see Aura sitting in her garden, silent as ever.

THE WORLD goes on, but what happens to Kite?

Comment: In the *.hack//Versus* game, It's stated that Sora and her friends return after a year after the events in *.hack//Beyond* movie.

Comment: There is no certitude as of now as there is still no sequel apart from the .hack//versus ova in which sora is not featured.